# How to disable DataTemplate at a specific place?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Consider the following model:

```
var model = new object[] { "Ala ma kota", DateTime.Now };
```

Now, let's suppose, that we have the following DataTemplates for ListBox displaying this model:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>String:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type sys:DateTime}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock>Data i czas:</TextBlock>
                <Calendar DisplayDate={Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

If we run such program, quite funny effect will be achieved:

[image: Too much styling]

Is there a way to disable `DataTemplate` on some level? I'd like to "block" it in the second DataTemplate, such that the calendar will be displayed correctly.

Comment: @RohitVats I would like to tell WPF not to search for a `DataTemplate` for `String` when templating the element of type `DateTime`. In simple words: I want the `Calendar` to be displayed correctly :)

Comment: Ok got you now. Check out my answer if that helps.!!

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of is to ***take advantage of resource lookup behaviour*** in WPF. It traverses up the Visual tree till found a default resource for a control.

You can **define resource locally for string inside dataTemplate of DateTime** so that it gets applied locally for your DateTime template and for others it will continue to behave same:

```
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock>Data i czas:</TextBlock>
                    <Calendar DisplayDate="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +1 - solves the effects. But is there a way to solve the cause? eg. to tell WPF "Now stop searching for the datatemplate and use default one"? Like setting `Style` to `{x:Null}` reverts look of any control to the default one.

Comment: I don't there is any other way to achieve that (as per my knowledge of course).